# Update the "last modified date" of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, date, ctime

I want to set the last modified date of a file to the current date in order to avoid [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) caching (unfortunately I didn't find a better way).

So I wrote that:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const file = 'test.txt';

// save the content of the file
const content = fs.readFileSync(file);

// modify the file
fs.appendFileSync(file, ' ');

// restore the file content
fs.writeFileSync(file, content);
```

It works but meh...
It's really ugly and it's very slow and memory consuming for big files.

Comment: You can use `touch -m test.txt`

Comment: @yuko `touch` isn't cross-platform. I search something that will work everytime so a native Node.js function or a good NPM module.

Comment: Maybe you'll find `fs.utimes` useful

Comment: @yuko I've just tested it and it works thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted from https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/12/17/touch-file-nodejs/:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const filename = 'test.txt';
const time = new Date();

try {
  fs.utimesSync(filename, time, time);
} catch (err) {
  fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(filename, 'w'));
}
```

fs.utimesSync is used here to prevent existing file contents from being overwritten.

It also updates the last modification timestamp of the file, which is consistent with what POSIX touch does.